# "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError" while placing order

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, express, mongoose

Im trying to make an ecommerce app and the frontend is all done but when i place an order i get this message.
[image: This is the error in the terminal.]

I rechecked every file but i cant find where its coming from. I followed the process from a udemy course but it just doesnt work. i got no response from the instructor and his code seems to work fine.
Here is the github master repo for the course.
I am stuck here for 10 days. HELP!
https://github.com/bluebits-academy/mern-stack-ecommerce

This is my Order.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    orderItems: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'OrderItem',
        required:true
    }],
    shippingAddress1: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    shippingAddress2: {
        type: String,
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    zip: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    country: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'Pending',
    },
    totalPrice: {
        type: Number,
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    },
    dateOrdered: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
})

orderSchema.virtual('id').get(function () {
    return this._id.toHexString();
});

orderSchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true,
});

exports.Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);



/**
Order Example:

{
    "orderItems" : [
        {
            "quantity": 3,
            "product" : "5fcfc406ae79b0a6a90d2585"
        },
        {
            "quantity": 2,
            "product" : "5fd293c7d3abe7295b1403c4"
        }
    ],
    "shippingAddress1" : "Flowers Street , 45",
    "shippingAddress2" : "1-B",
    "city": "Prague",
    "zip": "00000",
    "country": "Czech Republic",
    "phone": "+420702241333",
    "user": "5fd51bc7e39ba856244a3b44"
}

**/
```

This is my api for order. orders.js

```
const {Order} = require('../models/order');
const express = require('express');
const { OrderItem } = require('../models/order-item');
const router = express.Router();

router.get(`/`, async (req, res) =>{
    const orderList = await Order.find().populate('user', 'name').sort({'dateOrdered': -1});

    if(!orderList) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    } 
    res.send(orderList);
})

router.get(`/:id`, async (req, res) =>{
    const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate('user', 'name')
    .populate({ 
        path: 'orderItems', populate: {
            path : 'product', populate: 'category'} 
        });

    if(!order) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    } 
    res.send(order);
})

router.post('/', async (req,res)=>{
    const orderItemsIds = Promise.all(req.body.orderItems.map(async (orderItem) =>{
        let newOrderItem = new OrderItem({
            quantity: orderItem.quantity,
            product: orderItem.product
        })

        newOrderItem = await newOrderItem.save();

        return newOrderItem._id;
    }))
    const orderItemsIdsResolved =  await orderItemsIds;

    const totalPrices = await Promise.all(orderItemsIdsResolved.map(async (orderItemId)=>{
        const orderItem = await OrderItem.findById(orderItemId).populate('product', 'price');
        const totalPrice = orderItem.product.price * orderItem.quantity;
        return totalPrice
    }))

    const totalPrice = totalPrices.reduce((a,b) => a +b , 0);

    let order = new Order({
        orderItems: orderItemsIdsResolved,
        shippingAddress1: req.body.shippingAddress1,
        shippingAddress2: req.body.shippingAddress2,
        city: req.body.city,
        zip: req.body.zip,
        country: req.body.country,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        status: req.body.status,
        totalPrice: totalPrice,
        user: req.body.user,
    })
    order = await order.save();

    if(!order)
    return res.status(400).send('the order cannot be created!')

    res.send(order);
})


router.put('/:id',async (req, res)=> {
    const order = await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        {
            status: req.body.status
        },
        { new: true}
    )

    if(!order)
    return res.status(400).send('the order cannot be update!')

    res.send(order);
})


router.delete('/:id', (req, res)=>{
    Order.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id).then(async order =>{
        if(order) {
            await order.orderItems.map(async orderItem => {
                await OrderItem.findByIdAndRemove(orderItem)
            })
            return res.status(200).json({success: true, message: 'the order is deleted!'})
        } else {
            return res.status(404).json({success: false , message: "order not found!"})
        }
    }).catch(err=>{
       return res.status(500).json({success: false, error: err}) 
    })
})

router.get('/get/totalsales', async (req, res)=> {
    const totalSales= await Order.aggregate([
        { $group: { _id: null , totalsales : { $sum : '$totalPrice'}}}
    ])

    if(!totalSales) {
        return res.status(400).send('The order sales cannot be generated')
    }

    res.send({totalsales: totalSales.pop().totalsales})
})

router.get(`/get/count`, async (req, res) =>{
    const orderCount = await Order.countDocuments((count) => count)

    if(!orderCount) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    } 
    res.send({
        orderCount: orderCount
    });
})

router.get(`/get/userorders/:userid`, async (req, res) =>{
    const userOrderList = await Order.find({user: req.params.userid}).populate({ 
        path: 'orderItems', populate: {
            path : 'product', populate: 'category'} 
        }).sort({'dateOrdered': -1});

    if(!userOrderList) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    } 
    res.send(userOrderList);
})



module.exports =router;
```

And this is my order-item.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const orderItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    product: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product'
    }
})

exports.OrderItem = mongoose.model('OrderItem', orderItemSchema);
```

Do comment if you need any more codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error :

```
ValidationError : OrderItem validation failed : product : Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{..}" at path "product"
```

means that: **the "product" property in OrderItem expect an ObjectId**, you can see it in the schema :

```
const orderItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    product: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product'
    }
})
```

**but you're passing an object** into it here :

```
let newOrderItem = new OrderItem({
            quantity: orderItem.quantity,
            product: orderItem.product //<------ orderItem.product is an object
        })

        newOrderItem = await newOrderItem.save();
```

I think it should be :

```
let newOrderItem = new OrderItem({
            quantity: orderItem.quantity,
            product: orderItem.product.id // we only need the id of product
        })

        newOrderItem = await newOrderItem.save();
```

You may need to log `orderItem.product` before creating a new OrderItem to ensure the data inside it.